# Can I change Wireshark's HomePlug AV protocol info from "Unknown, 0x6076" to "CM_MNBC_SOUND.IND"

Tags: wireshark

Currently, Wireshark (2.2.4) displays (for Protocol "HomePlug AV") "MAC Management, Unknown 0x6076" in the Info column; I would like to display names such as CM_MNBC_SOUND.IND in this example.

The strings "MAC Management" and "HomePlug AV" are inside of the libwireshark.dll and the "Decode As ..." dialogue doesn't offer any suitable field. (In fact, it resembles the documentation's dialogue very little.)

Running under Windows 7 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the value of 0x6076 to be interpreted as you want, the Wireshark [`packet-homeplug-av.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-homeplug-av.c;h=5ce4a188d7feb2530daf54fcfa14b6476b0b43c5;hb=HEAD) source code would need to be modified.  Specifically, the `homeplug_av_mmtype_vals[]` array would need to be modified accordingly.

If this is a legitimate change, you should file a [Wireshark bug report](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/) requesting it, or you could make the change yourself if you're able to and [submit a patch](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/SubmittingPatches).

Comment: Thank you, Christopher. That's what I was afraid of. Of course fixing that would help everyone else. (There are a whole raft of HomePlug AV MM types that are not decoded, so perhaps I'll take a whack at it.)